# Vue Element bind select in list with ID

Tags: vue.js

I need to do simple [drop-down list](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) (aka select) with Vue Element. I need to put selected value id in variable, but I can't understand how to do it with Element. I know how to do it in pure Vue, but it's do not working with Element.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/dxh2mbkv/

```
    <el-select clearable placeholder="Select" class="SelectFullWidth" >
  <el-option
    v-for="item in people"
     :value="item.name" >
  </el-option>
 </el-select>
```

I need to get selected id in variable.

There is small issue with example. It's now working, because I have never used Vue Element with jsfiddle.

Pure Vue solution that I need reimplement in Vue element https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/3x0z3vzk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle to make it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/dxh2mbkv/33/ (if you can't see labels in dropdown it seems to be jsfiddle issue, when you open developer tools in your browser or shrink your screen width, they should appear)

```
 <el-select clearable placeholder="Select" class="SelectFullWidth" v-model="selectedPerson">
  <el-option
    v-for="item in people"
    :key="item.key"
    :label="item.name"
     :value="item.key" >
  </el-option>
 </el-select>
 Key: {{selectedPerson}}
```

What I did was I added `v-model="selectedPerson"` to `el-select`, changed your `:value` in `el-option` from `item.name` to `item.key` and added `:label="item.name"` to display option labels properly. And since your `selectedPerson` binds to a number, I changed it's default value to `null`.